# Crontab - Restart apache every 3 hours

Tags: apache, debian, cron

My server is currently suffering from some problems due to visitors lag and i think the best solution for it, is to restart apache every 2/3 hours or so
How can i do this through cronjob ?

Comment: That is not fixing the problem - just putting off the inevitable. I would explore the problem a bit more before you have a lot more users. I would also explore the various configuration parameters for Apache. There are quite a few.

Comment: @EdHeal i think this question is a duplicate of "how can i load my gun faster to shoot my own foot?"

Comment: @Ray - Just thought that in Apache shutdown mode (before doing the start bit) the web site is offline whilst the current transactions are completing. So Osa web site is going to have a break in service every couple of hours. (This could also have pages without images, AJAX not working etc...)

Comment: i dont have users or anything that is related to break a running service, its just because my vps performances are low and my website already gets loads of visitors who makes a lot of lag and take the whole website down, i tried many fixes.. none of them has worked and so there i am going to try this one, i think apache needs to relax every few hours

Comment: @Osa if your memory is getting expended and your http processes are jamming up, you might want look at lowering the number of requests per child in your http.  A properly configured apache should never need to be restarted or relaxed.   If apache is configured optimally for the server resources available and  you can't handle your traffic you need to add another server or upgrade you existing one.

Comment: my ram seems totally fine, its already 2GB to handle big stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you want to do this?If you are experiencing a specific problem with Apache.It Will definitely  be more beneficial for you to have a look into  the access/error logs, and make adjustments accordingly.Give us some more information and we can look into your logs and give you a more appropriate solution.

**None the less heres the cron to restart apache.**

0 */3 * * */ root/restart_apache > /dev/null 2>&1

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: This would restart every 15 minutes, also the intermediate script is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks h0tw1r3:P Bit rusty in this department and didnt check correctly!:)

Comment: why did u remove the "restart_apache" content?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I have updated, and checked the script confirmed working thanks Osa

Comment: Also i think theres a missing space between * and /root, right ?

Comment: i dont think u made the correct update, lol!

Comment: Won't this run every one minute on every hour divisible by 3? I think the first * should be a 0 to run on the hour only.

Answer (score 1):

I can almost guarantee this 'fix' will not address your real issue.  Why not post your Http.conf settings and a little info on your server resources (memory, cpus) and we might help fix your config issues.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding to the crontab of an individual user (root), I would add hacks like this to /etc/cron.d.

Change 'apache2' to whatever the init script is on debian.

```
echo '* */3 * * * root /etc/init.d/apache2 restart 2>&1 >/dev/null' > /etc/cron.d/apachesux
```