# how restart or reload nginx using php

Tags: php, nginx, centos

i change nginx conf file with php
next i want restart nginx.
but can not restart nginx

```
<?php
    if(exec("service nginx restart")) {
        echo "ok shd";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
<hr>
<?php
    if(exec("/etc/init.d/nginx reload")) {
        echo "ok shd";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
<hr>
<?php
    if(exec("/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload")) {
        echo "ok shd";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

output is :

```
error<hr>
error<hr>
error
```

To do `exec("service nginx restart")` I need acces to php-fpm as root, so i go to `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf`

```
user = nobody
group = nobody
```

and change it to:

```
user = root
group = root
```

and next enter `service php-fpm restart`

output:

```
Starting php-fpm [11-Feb-2016 05:14:33] ERROR: [pool www] please specify user and group other than root
[11-Feb-2016 05:14:33] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
 failed
```

and this means it can't be run as root.

So how can I restart or reload nginx using php?

Comment: When you `shell_exec()` or `exec()` your user is `nginx`, not `root`.

Comment: @phabarest: No it is not. This is about PHP which does not run as part of the nginx process group, never mind its uid.

Comment: so you [removed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35339230/revisions) all your code from your question?

Answer (score 2):

> I need acces to php-fpm as root

**OMG NO**

Theres's a very good reason PHP-FPM won't run as root - because its a really, **really** bad thing to do.

If you really must expose this functionality via a webserver then do it via [sudo](http://aplawrence.com/Basics/sudo.html). Similarly *any* changes to your system config should be via sudo.

BTW: one crucially important thing missing from your script is ignore_user_abort(). When (if) nginx is restarted by PHP the connection to the browser will be lost. By default, PHP will terminate at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Most people will tell you to never run `php` as `root`, however, it's fairly safe to do if you have multiple `php-fpm.sock` files, and you have multiple levels of security to ensure than only you are able to execute `php` with `root` permissions. Remember, php should only execute with the minimum permissions required.

**NB**

I am using Centos, so some of the file names, paths, and commands I use may be slightly different for you.

**Security**

1. Create a separate `login portal` that only you have access to. You could do this by opening up a port and using your firewall and / or nginx rules to allow only your IP address (ideally a dedicated IP address that you can VPN into). I would also recommend setting up google authenticator for your secure portal.
2. In your `nginx` configuration, you are now able to define 2 different sock files under separate server configurations.
3. Create a copy of `php-fpm.conf`. The file should be included in `/etc/php-fpm.conf`.
4. Restart `php-fpm`, then view its status to make sure it's working correctly. You may need to manually change the permission and group of `/var/run/php-fpm/` and it's contents if you get permission errors with `nginx`.

**Make php run as root**

1. Change `user` and `group` to `root` (like you already have done).
2. Open `php-fpm.service`. I typed `nano /lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service` via ssh console.
3. Change `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize` to `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize -R`. The `-R` allows php-fpm to run as root.
4. Restart `daemon`. If you are using `centos`, type `systemctl daemon-reload`.

**Edit**

If the only reason you want to make `php` execute as `root` is to restart nginx, then you are probably better off doing it by setting up a cron job. See: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498400/restart-apache-service-automatically-using-cron-12am-daily) or manually via `ssh`.